# How to inverse geocode in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this code, this works perfectly to save my latitude and longitude. I read some articles here, they doesnt work for me. I know how to code with PHP but jquery and javascript are my frenemy.

I just can't edit cos' i dont know the syntax of this. I want to add the value to and input with the id, but i have to add the Decoded Address.  I knoe Google maps have a way, they call it Geocode or something like that.

I have also a working model, but with geolocalization, and i can't change the vars, because i dont know how to. :(

PD: Is there a course Javascript for Dummies? It will help me to understand better.

```
                    function initialize() {
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.1675922,-86.8563953);
                    var mapProp = {
                    center:myLatlng,
                    zoom:13,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

                  };
                  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: myLatlng,
                      map: map,
                      title: 'Tu casa u oficina',
                      draggable:true  
                  });

                    document.getElementById('latitud').value= 21.1675922
                    document.getElementById('longitud').value= -86.8563953  
                    document.getElementById('direccion').value= 'Direccion desconocida'  

                    // marker drag event
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag',function(event) {
                        document.getElementById('latitud').value = event.latLng.lat();
                        document.getElementById('longitud').value = event.latLng.lng();                    
                    });

                    //marker drag event end
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
                        document.getElementById('latitud').value = event.latLng.lat();
                        document.getElementById('longitud').value = event.latLng.lng();
                    });                    

                }

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? You say you have a working model for geolocating the users address, maybe post that instead. From what I see, you're trying to geolocate a users address when they enter the page, and show their lat & lng in the form input fields?

Comment: I want a extra input field, to save the "1st Ave, 77899 Canada"

Answer (score 0):

If you want a guide on how to do Reverse Geocoding, then you can check the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=en#ReverseGeocoding) for it. It will provide you an example and sample code on how to make reverse geocoding by [location](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=en#reverse-geocoding-by-location) and [Place ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=en#reverse-geocoding-by-place-id). For more information, check this [tutorial](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/03/05/Simple-Reverse-Geocoding-Example/).